# Make ActivityResultLauncher open gallery directly not file explorer

Tags: android, gallery

As the doc said, we can choose only image from gallery in the following way using [ActivityResultLauncher](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new GetContent(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            // Handle the returned Uri
        }
});

mGetContent.launch("image/*");
```

It almost satisfied my requirement, except that it does NOT open gallery directly. I have to click the gallery icon manually. Is it possible to open gallery directly?

[image: opened by laucher]

Comment: There is no requirement for a phone to *have* a gallery app, let alone for that particular contract to use one. That being said, you may have better luck using [this contract](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly).